# Java example: Is this really accessing a static method in a non-static way?

Tags: java

I am just working through some examples from my text book, writing the code in Eclipse to figure it out.

This is the code for the method I have a question about:

```
public void run() {
    //Get the lock before entering the loop
    synchronized(getClass()) {
        for (int i =0; i<N; i++) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " is tired");
            
            try{
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            
            System.out.println(getName() + " is rested");
        }
```

On line the line with:

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(DELAY)
```

Eclipse gives a warning: "The static method sleep(long) from the type Thread should be accessed in a static way". Eclipse suggests the following solution:

```
Thread.currentThread();
Thread.sleep(DELAY);
```

I don't understand why it makes a difference (if it really does). Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is a static method and causes *the current thread* to sleep for the specified amount of time. Thus the `currentThread()` call is superfluous, and can potentially be confusing since it almost implies that you could make *another thread* sleep by using similar code (you can't).

The best way to write that code is simply:

```
Thread.sleep(DELAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

Code in question has nothing to do with threads. Eclipse just says that you should access static method `sleep` directly via class name, not via instanse: `Thread.sleep(DELAY)`.

Any static method `static ... f()` of class `C` should be accessed as `C.f()` for clarity (and brevity).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I removed the threadpool tag from the question.

Answer (score 2):

The Thread.sleep() is already a static method and affects the current thread. There is no need to call currentThread().

Answer (score 1):

Thread.delay is a static method.  It doesn't require an instance to invoke it - you can just say Thread.delay().

Thread.currentThread() returns you an reference to the current thread.  You can invoke a static method on it, but you don't strictly need the reference and it's not used at all.  You could equally do this:

```
new Thread().delay(100);
```

... and it would still make the current thread sleep - not the thread that we just created.

So eclipse is telling you that the better, less confusing way is Thread.delay(100).

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but the warning probably is "The static method ... should be accessed **in a static way**" (not ... should be accessed **in a non-static way**).

In fact it is confusing to call

```
someThread.sleep(1000)
```

because as Thread.sleep() is a static method in is not called "against" someThread but on the current Thread.

So the message says "access static methods in a static way" :)

Comment: You are right. It says "The static method ... should be accessed in a static way". I did an edit just now.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any difference in execution. However second option Thread.sleep() is more readable as user does not get confused thinking its an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

By accesing the method as `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` it gives the impression that it is an instance method, to avoid confusion, Eclipse suggests you access static methods through the owner class and by this make evident that they are, in fact, static.

Answer (score 0):

As Victor Sorokin wrote the warning has nothing to do with the example code with Threads.  Here is another example where, in Eclipse, we get the same compiler warning:

```
OptionBuilder.withArgName(PROPERTY_ARG).hasArg(true).isRequired(false).create(PROPERTY_ARG_OPTION);
```

This is using the Apache Commons CLI library.  OptionBuilder uses the 'fluent' builder pattern.  The only way I see to fix the warning is use the recommended Eclipse hint, that breaks the line into multiple statements, or prepend an annotation to ignore the warning.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
currentThread.wait(DELAY);
```

Comment: You haven't understood the question?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14851776)

Comment: @bsiamionau A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @FelixSFD are you kidding me, man? This is the code, copy-pasted from the question itself.

Comment: @bsiamionau The question uses `sleep`, whereas this answer uses `wait`. So it isn't copied, but it also doesn't make a sense as an answer, because it fails the scope (`wait` is not static like `sleep`). The bad thing on SO, any attempt to answer is considered as an answer and shouldn't be flagged. Voting is the only option. I also don't like that rule, but that's not my decision :D.

Comment: Oh gosh. This is getting very serious. This is a open platform, we are trying to help each other and value others opinion. I merely presented this point to see possibilities of a better approach. Thanks for sharing your opinion and wish you have a great day. Thanks Tom, bsiamionau and FelixSFD

Comment: No, Ram Prasath, this is no forum where we all life in a spiritual world where everything is nice and useful. SO only works correctly if the content has a certain quality and your post is just meaningless code without any description why it should be helpful. And that description is necessary to see why this code, which misses the meaning of this question, is on-topic.